# VB.Net - Looking for Design Pattern - For Each Instead of For with index

Tags: vb.net, for-loop, foreach, indexing, each

Using VB.Net, I'm looking for best practices in dealing with the following idiom:

```
For i as Integer = 0 To o1.Count - 1
  o1(i).x = o2(i).x
Next
```

What I really want is something VB.Net doesn't offer -- additional and simultaneous iterators on For Each statements.

```
For Each m1 As c1 In o1, m2 As c2 In o2
  m1.x = m2.x
Next
```

I'm interested in both Linq and non-Linq recommendations, comments about Copy method design, comparisions to C# or other languages.

Comment: What you're trying to achieve is a perfect example of a `For-loop`. You want to modify collections and you want to access them by index.

Comment: What you're discussing is an idiom, not a design pattern, btw :)

Comment: I would add, why is a bad practice as you said to use a for-loop???

Comment: I agree that the for loop is perfect for this. Other solutions won't be as clean as this.

Comment: Indeed idiom is a better term: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_idiom

Comment: Doesn't anyone have a Linq solution? Don't other languages have a more elegant way to express this idiom?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I submitted a request to extend the For Each statement to implement additional and simultaneous iterators.

http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2923571-allow-additional-clauses-on-for-each-similar-to-c-

I'm still interested in other solutions but until then, this is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure your actual real world situation is more complicated than the example you have shown, but I thought it was worth mentioning that, if all you are doing is trying to copy an entire list of items from one list to another, you can simply do something like this:

```
Dim list2 = New List(Of Object)(list1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to do with this. We could probably help you better if you elaborate a little more on your problem.

If both lists are of the same Type you could append one list to the other and then use a for each on just one list.